# Create a container in win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi

I am a beginner in Win32 API. I am trying to create a little application that requires a container, but I have problems doing it.

In HTML, I will show you what I want. Its the following code:

```css
div{width:120px; height:300px; display:block; overflow-y:auto;}
button{display:list-item;list-style:none; margin-bottom:3px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>button 1</button>
  <button>button 2</button>
  <button>button 3</button>
  <button>button 4</button>
  <button>button 5</button>
  <button>button 6</button>
  <button>button 7</button>
  <button>button 8</button>
  <button>button 9</button>
  <button>button 10</button>
  <button>button 11</button>
  <button>button 12</button>
  <button>button 13</button>
  <button>button 14</button>
</div>
```

I have tried to repeat the same display in C++ using this code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

const char *ClsName = "classname";
const char *WndName = "Windows";
HINSTANCE hInst;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG        Msg;
    HWND       hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX WndClsEx;

    hInst = hInstance;

    // Create the application window
    WndClsEx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    WndClsEx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    WndClsEx.lpfnWndProc = WndProcedure;
    WndClsEx.cbClsExtra = 0;
    WndClsEx.cbWndExtra = 0;
    WndClsEx.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_QUESTION);
    WndClsEx.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    WndClsEx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_PEN);
    WndClsEx.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCEA(109);
    WndClsEx.lpszClassName = ClsName;
    WndClsEx.hInstance = hInst;

    WndClsEx.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_QUESTION);
    // Register the application
    RegisterClassEx(&WndClsEx);

    // Create the window object
    hWnd = CreateWindow(ClsName,
        WndName,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInst,
        NULL);

    // Find out if the window was created successfully
    if (!hWnd) // If the window was not created,
        return 0; // stop the application

                  // Display the window to the user
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    // Decode and treat the messages
    // as long as the application is running
    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    return Msg.wParam;
};
//classname

//classname
using namespace std;

 LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
     static HWND ws[50], st, sd;
     switch (msg) {
     case WM_DESTROY:
         PostQuitMessage(0); break;
     case WM_CREATE:
         sd = CreateWindow(ClsName, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VSCROLL |WS_HSCROLL| WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE, 10, 10, 200, 600, hwnd, NULL, hInst, NULL);//Container
         for (int i = 0; i < 114; i++) {
         ws[i] = CreateWindow("Button", ("Button" + to_string(i)).c_str(), WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD, 10, 25*i + 10, 150, 20, sd, (HMENU)(i + 1), hInst, NULL); //Buttons
         };      
         break;
     default: return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam); break;
     }
 }
```

With this code, I get a container that is infinitely repeated in the the main window.

This is a screenshot of the result;

[image]

I do not understand the result. It seems I have used a loop but I did not.

Comment: I think you are getting a WM_CREATE when the button is created, which creates another button which sends another message, forming the loop

Comment: `VM_CREATE` ? Doesn't look like you have shown the real code.

Comment: You've not posted your actual code, because there is no such message as `VM_CREATE`. Also, what does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: Don't post link to external website and expect people to download your code. `imgur.com` is okay for images, 1drv.ms is not okay.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems I have used a loop but I did not.

Actually, you did.  You have a *recursive loop* in your `WM_CREATE` message handler.

Your `WinMain()` calls `CreateWindow()` to create the initial `ClsName` window, and then your `WM_CREATE` handler calls `CreateWindow()` to create *another* `ClsName` window (which uses the same `WndProcedure()` for its messages).  When that second window receives `WM_CREATE`, you are calling `CreateWindow()` to create *another* `ClsName` window.  And another `ClsName` window, and so on, endlessly.

DO NOT create a new `ClsName` window inside the `WM_CREATE` of an earlier `ClsName` window.  You have defined a `WndName` class name, but you are not registering or using it.  Maybe you intended to do so.  Alternatively, use a standard [`STATIC` control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760769.aspx) for the container.

Also, your `WM_CREATE` message handler has another error.  It is creating 114 child buttons, but is storing them in a static array that can only hold 50 `HWND`s.  As such, you have a buffer overflow that will corrupt memory.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first off, I think you mean WM_CREATE (not VM_CREATE) - have you posted your actual code? Because i would doubt this works at all.

Secondly, WM_CREATE is a message sent to you by windows after you have called CreateWindow. See doco here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632619(v=vs.85).aspx

In your case you're going to be creating an infinite loop of window creation followed by notification messages.

Comment: I have just posted the code. here is a onedrive link to the code. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AslOWnUisL_wgYY5BDUHNYR6l-b56g
Thanks for all.